# Append entry to RDD using a loop

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to append an entry to an existing RDD each iteration of a loop. My code until now is:

```
var newY = sc.emptyRDD[MatrixEntry]
for (j <- 0 until 8000) {
  var arrTmp = Array(MatrixEntry(j, j, 1))
  var rddTmp = sc.parallelize(arrTmp)
  newY = newY.union(rddTmp)
}
```

Making these 8000 iterations I get an error when I try to take(10) from that RDD but if I try with smaller number every thing is ok.
The error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPartitions(UnionRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)`

Help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you get is a duplicate of [Stackoverflow due to long RDD Lineage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461804/stackoverflow-due-to-long-rdd-lineage), but your code shouldn't be with at all.

If you want identity matrix just map with range:

```
val newY = spark.sparkContext.range(0, 8000).map(j => MatrixEntry(j, j, 1))
```

Loop with parallelize doesn't scale and keeps all data in the driver memory [Why does SparkContext.parallelize use memory of the driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46262236/8371915)